# Maintaining a set of values

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

In my document , I am maintaining a set under the field setValues. I am able to add values to it using update API script support , but then its adding duplicate elements to this value on insertion if the element is already present. So i want to add an element if only its not present in the array. How can I emulate this set operation.

Suppose this is my field:

```
 setValues = [
        {
            color: "red",
            value: "#f00"
        },
        {
            color: "green",
            value: "#0f0"
        },
        {
            color: "blue",
            value: "#00f"
        },
        {
            color: "cyan",
            value: "#0ff"
        },
        {
            color: "magenta",
            value: "#f0f"
        },
        {
            color: "yellow",
            value: "#ff0"
        },
        {
            color: "black",
            value: "#000"
        }
    ]
```

Here if I want to add the following element to setValues

```
   `{
     color: "magenta",
     value:#f0f
    }
```

It should check whether this element is already there in the setValue array, and since this entry is already there,the new element should not be added. But if I try to add an element which was not there in the array,it should add and get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use scripting in [Update API](http://blog.qbox.io/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting) and traverse through the elements to find if there is a duplicate element. Then based on it , do a insert or no insert.

**Script to apply**

```
 source = ctx._source
    Boolean isAdded = false;
    for(page in source.setValues){
            if(page.name == newValue.name){
                    isAdded = true
            }
    }
    if(!isAdded){
            source.setValues += newValue
    }
```

**Sample request**

```
 curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
  "script": "referAboveScript",
  "params": {
    "newValue": {
      "color": "magenta",
      "value": "#f0f"
    }
  }
}'
```